# python - django: why am I getting this error: AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'?

Tags: python, django

I have the following python code:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()
```

In a python shell, I am trying to run:

```
p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
p.was_published_today()
```

The first line works fine but the second line gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You probably want `import datetime`, not `from datetime import datetime`.

`date` is a class on the datetime module, but it is also a method on the `datetime.datetime` class.

Comment: or `from datetime import datetime, date`

Answer (score 38):

The top answer is correct, but if you don't want to import all of datetime you can write

```
from datetime import date
```

and then replace

```
datetime.date.today()
```

with

```
date.today()
```

Comment: `datetime.date.today()` didn't work, but `date.today()` worked.

Answer (score 6):

You need do like this one (ipython output)

```
In [9]: datetime.today().date()
Out[9]: datetime.date(2011, 2, 5)
```

So need to be

```
def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.today().date()
```