# DateField doesn't take date.today as default

Tags: python, django, datefield

Python version 2.7

Django version 1.11

Trying to make my first Django app saving documents, here the part of **models.py**

```
class Docs(models.Model):
    FacilityRef = models.ForeignKey(Facility)
    Date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Link = models.FileField(upload_to='Docs/%Y/%m/%d')
```

When making migration got the following error:

> Date = models.DateField(default=date.today) NameError: name 'date'
>   is not defined

Part of **views.py**:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import datetime
```

Part of **models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    import datetime
```

Tried to insert the following strings in **views.py** and **models.py** as it mentioned in 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329589/python-global-name-date-is-not-defined)
[and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934248/nameerror-name-datetime-is-not-defined)
it didn't help

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
```

What kind of import should I do to make this function work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date` is a submodule of the `datetime` module. You never import a module called `date`, so you get a NameError when you try to call it. It should be

```
import datetime

Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

or

```
from datetime import date

Date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

Comment: Great! and the following way works too: `from datetime import date`